# Safari dropdown menu covers content

Tags: html, css, wordpress, safari

My site is [www.denieuwekhl.nl](http://www.denieuwekhl.nl) when is safari you make it responsive and click on the menu the dropdown overlays the content. You cant inspect with safari so it is hard to see where the problem is. On all my other browser it is working. The display is block.

It is a wordpress site. I used the plugin max mege menu. Mabby it has to do something with that? But I dont think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari is not recognizing `height: unset`. Change `height: unset` to `height: auto` to fix this issue.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1022px) and (min-width: 767px) {
   .site-header {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because of you write wrong css for .site header class in
media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1022px) and (min-width: 767px){
 .site-header{
  height: auto;
  width: 79%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
```

Set height:auto; instead of height:unset;